# edit all rows in a column, data table c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I've got a data table that's populated with data from a file that's been read in. I wish to then edit all rows in a specific column. In my case dividing the speed column by 1.6 to convert to MPH from KMH.

so far, I've tried using the below code but am getting an index out of range

```
foreach (DataRow row in data_table.Rows) {
     row["Speed (KM/H)"] = speed[x]/1.6;
}
```

here is the code that fills the data table with the file

```
 private void display_hrm_data() {
     /* array heart_rate_table set to heart_rate
      * adds each column
      * for every piece of data in heart_rate_table add rows
      */        
     data_table.Columns.Add("Heart Rate (BPM)", typeof(string));
     data_table.Columns.Add("Speed (KM/H)", typeof(int));
     data_table.Columns.Add("Cadence (RPM)", typeof(int));
     data_table.Columns.Add("Altitude (M)", typeof(int));
     data_table.Columns.Add("Power (Watts)", typeof(int));
     data_table.Columns.Add("Time (Seconds)", typeof(int));
     for (int x = 0; x < heart_rate.Count - 1; x++) {
         time = time + 1;
         data_table.Rows.Add(heart_rate[x],speed[x],cadence[x],altitude[x],power[x], time);
     }
     dgv_data.DataSource = data_table;
}
```

Comment: what is x in speed[x]??

Comment: @apomene rows from the file im reading in. It holds a lot of data, so im using a for loop to read specific lines

Comment: Where is speed declared and where are you using x as an indexer. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Field` and `SetField` extensions which are strongly typed, otherwise you need to cast the fields manually from object to `int`. You get the `IndexOutOfRange` exception because `x` seems to be an invalid index. Use the column name.

So for example:

```
DataColumn speedCol = data_table.Columns["Speed (KM/H)"];
foreach (DataRow row in data_table.Rows)
{
    int oldSpeed = row.Field<int>(speedCol);
    row.SetField(speedCol, oldSpeed / 1.6); 
}
```